# Mysterious Black Lines in Word When Using In-House VB.Net Application

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

A little backstory. I work at an organization that uses Mail Merge and SQL Databases to populate letters with names/addresses. Those letters are sent out to our donors as thank yous. These letters change frequently, and new ones come up at least 10 times a month.

To simplify our process, I created a program that allows you to copy/paste the letter body content into rich text boxes and when you press the 'Go' button, it opens a pre-made Word template and replaces bookmarks in the template with the copied body content.

The program works great with most letters, but some of them have a problem where these thick black lines are created and I'm unable to do ANYTHING to remove them. I can't right click them, I can't delete them with Backspace or Delete, and I can't highlight them.

I'm thinking that the problem may come from hidden formatting. Some of the employees that write the letters are using the Mac version of Office 2016, and I'm using Windows version. I sent an RTF file that showed the black lines for me to someone who uses the Mac version, and they said they couldn't see the lines.

My question is, is there a way to get rid of these lines or prevent them in the future? I've thought about upgrading Office version to 2019 on both ends, but there are quite a few people that have their hands in these letters and it may be difficult to upgrade everyone.

Please refer to the attached image for visual reference. Names and personal details have been removed.[image]

EDIT: Here is the 'Go' code:

```
        'create temp rtf files to maintain rtf
    If strForm = "ANG2" Then
        txtPreD.SaveFile("\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\fptemp.rtf")
        txtPostD.SaveFile("\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\bptemp.rtf")
    ElseIf strForm = "ANGL" Then
        txtPreD.SaveFile("\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\predtemp.rtf")
        txtPostD.SaveFile("\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\postdtemp.rtf")
        txtBP.SaveFile("\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\bptemp.rtf")
    Else
        txtPreD.SaveFile("\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\predtemp.rtf")
        txtPostD.SaveFile("\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\postdtemp.rtf")
    End If

    'if bookmarks exists, insert appropriate rtf files
    If odoc.Bookmarks.Exists("fp") = True Then
        goWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fp").Select()
        goWord.Selection.InsertFile(FileName:="\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\fptemp.rtf")
    End If
    If odoc.Bookmarks.Exists("bp") = True Then
        goWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bp").Select()
        goWord.Selection.InsertFile(FileName:="\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\bptemp.rtf")
    End If
    If odoc.Bookmarks.Exists("PreD") = True Then
        goWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PreD").Select()
        goWord.Selection.InsertFile(FileName:="\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\predtemp.rtf")
    End If
    If odoc.Bookmarks.Exists("PostD") = True Then
        goWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PostD").Select()
        goWord.Selection.InsertFile(FileName:="\\server\AcknowledgementLetters\postdtemp.rtf")
    End If
```

Before this happens, the program checks to see which template it needs to open and opens it as a Word object (odoc). This bit of code is really the only important part. After this, I just click Finish it just saves the file once I'm done checking it for errors. Also, yes, the RTF files that it creates DO have the black lines as well. Here is another picture of the program itself just so you can get a better idea of what's going on.

[image]

Comment: can we take a look at the "go" code?

Comment: Have you checked whether these are page borders?

Comment: OctaCode, adding that into the original post now. Give me 5 minutes or so.

Cindy, is that in Format tab?

Comment: Sorry, meant Design tab. Cindy, I checked into that and it is set as None on Borders. If I click None and hit OK to double check, it doesn't change anything, so I assume there aren't any borders. Good suggestion to check, though!

Comment: I suggest to do following : create RTF from Win pc via your SW, and create the same RTF from Mac Pc via your SW.. then compare it (open rtf in notepad++ for ex.)

Comment: Daniel, when answering people in comments on Stack Overflow you need to prefix the screen name with `@`, otherwise we don't get a notification.

Comment: @PeterKsenak has an interesting suggestion. I'd use the Word Open XML file format, however (save as docx from both OS). Then use the Open XML SDK tool to open one of the files, then its "Compare" feature to open the other. This will highlight the differences (if any) in the underlying Word Open XML.

Comment: Is the screen shot originally one block, or two different screen shots "put together"? If the former, I'd guess paragraph borders, which would be in "Borders and Shadings" when a paragraph is selected. It might be part of a style definition. And also check that template whether it's set to automatically update styles (Developer tab, Add-ins button in the Add-ins group)

Comment: @PeterKsenak that's a good suggestion, but I'm confident the software I created won't work for a Mac. I don't really have a way of testing it either, as the people who generally write the letters and have a Mac are high up people that most likely wouldn't have time to let me mess around on it. I will say that the RTF I create IS different when viewed on a Mac. The black lines aren't there when viewed in Mac Office, but are in Windows Office.

Comment: @OctaCode tagging you in case you missed my edits.

Comment: @CindyMeister the screenshot is supposed to be one block of body content. It's the full first page of the letter. Also, I tried checking the "Automatically update" checkbox and it changed some font size (not a problem), and when I ran it through the program, the black lines had moved positions but were still visible. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Daniel, make sure the "automatically update styles is OFF". If that were on, it could have explained the behavior (style definitions being pulled in from a template). Did you check "Borders and Shading" for any one of the paragraphs? Ah, and do these borders PRINT, or is it only the display?

Comment: Also, open one of the RTF files that's being inserted and showing the lines: any lines in it?

Comment: @CindyMeister Oh, my apologies. Yes, it was off and I turned it back off. I double-checked and yes, the black lines do print in addition to being a nightmare when it comes to trying to 'prettify' the letter. I previously had tried not deleting the temp RTF files to see if the lines had appeared, and they do. However, I sent all of these RTF files to one of the Mac users, and the black lines did not appear for them.

Comment: Then I'd say you need to inspect the RTF files and delete what's causing the lines from those. And see to it that these files are then generated correctly.

Comment: @CindyMeister Right now, it just takes the text from the Rich Text Box and saves it using a SaveFile command. It may be a bad way of doing it, but it worked initially so I didn't think anything else of it. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201958/discussion-between-daniel-long-and-cindy-meister).